# Do I have damper on my wood stove?

Tags: chimney, air, firewood

I have a wood-burning stove, and I use it once or twice a year. When using using it I only use a knob (pull or push) which control the air intake.

I have noticed that when I use the stove I smell something in the living room. I just realized that my stove may not have a damper.

Can you please let me know if there is a damper for my fireplace? There is a thermometer attached to the pillar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would a damper to restrict the flow of exhaust gasses be at the top of the stove or would it be in the flue? If there is none, then it would be wide open. Why would that cause a smell inside? Is the exhaust flue partially blocked, e.g.,  by animal activity?

Comment: A slight wood burning smell is what some people expect/want from a wood burner/stove.  A smoky smell that causes tears and coughing and can be seen is not good/quite bad.  The flue/chimney should be cleaned at least once a year or more often.  A damper in the flue probably not needed/wanted.  A clean chimney/flue is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like there is one.

Common meaning of a fireplace damper is a plate to reduce flow into/in a chimney.

You should see a handle on top of the stove or in the chimney if you had a damper.

Comment: I don't see any handle. Is there a wood stove specialist that I can ask to inspect? What do  you call a person who inspect wood stove?

Comment: @sammy   You probably want a chimney cleaner to check and clean chimney/flue.  Blocked/dirty chimney can be dangerous causing chimney fires and/or a build up of CO gas(deadly) in the house.  No handle/no damper.